# How to replace a backslash with a double backslash without replacing existing double backslashes in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, replace

I have been provided a path from an external source I have no control over and need to store the file path in my SQL Server database.

The file path will appear similar to the below;

```
C:\\Users\\Temp\filepath\test\document.txt
```

I need to store these with all double backslashes as such

```
C:\\Users\\Temp\\filepath\\test\\document.txt
```

What is the correct way to replace `\` with `\\` without turning the string into this

```
C:\\\\Users\\\\Temp\\filepath\\test\\document.txt
```

with a `REPLACE` call?

Comment: perform another replace \\\\ with \\

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: I guess the real question is why you would ever want to do this...

Comment: @Charlieface I get the messed up filepaths from a third party application API call I have no control over. They require me to respond to them with double backslashes in API calls or their system falls over? I'm just a cog in a legacy machine

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a simple technique Gordon Linoff demonstrated some time ago. (can't recall the original post)

It will handle any number of repeating characters.  In this case `\`

In short, it expands, eliminates and finally normalizes.

**Example**

```
Declare @S varchar(150) = 'C:\\Users\\Temp\filepath\test\document.txt'

Select replace(replace(replace(@S,'\','†‡'),'‡†',''),'†‡','\\')
```

**Results**

```
C:\\Users\\Temp\\filepath\\test\\document.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

You can convert double to single and then single to double.

```
DECLARE @Path VARCHAR(100) = 'C:\\Users\\Temp\filepath\test\document.txt'
SELECT Replace(Replace(@Path, '\\', '\'), '\', '\\')
```

Comment: I like John Cappelletti's answer better, as it handles any number of consecutive backslashes.